# connect upload and submit button of two different forms

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, backend

I am formatting a table in which there was one column ACTION with actions such as **upload**, **download**, **deliver**, **reject**. Now I need to separate that into two columns like UPLOAD (upload, download) and ACTION ( deliver and reject). Now the problem is the functionality of upload and deliver is in one form.

```
<td class="content-writing-action">
    @if($data->status==2 || $data->status==0)
    <form action="{{ route('upload-content') }}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-sty form-button ">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $data->id }}">
            <div class="choose_file">
                <a><i class="fa fa-upload"></i></a>
                <input name="attachment" id="attachment" type="file" accept=".doc,.docx,.txt,.pdf" required/>
            </div>
            <button id="submit" class="content-writing-btn"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
        </form>
        
        <form action="{{route('content.reject')}}" id="rejectForm" method="post"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              class="form-sty form-button ">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <input type="hidden" value="{{$data->id}}" name="reject_id">
            {{--  <textarea required placeholder="Enter your reason to reject the order." style="display: none;" class="form-control reject_reason" name="reject_reason_{{$data->id}}" id="reject_reason_{{$data->id}}" rows="2"></textarea>--}}
            <i class="fas fa-times text-danger website_reject reject_reason"
               id="reject_{{$data->id}}"
               ></i>
        </form>
    @endif
</td>
```

now, how can I make the functionality of upload and submit into two different forms? how to connect the **upload** button of one form to the **submit** button of another form.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In pure html, the value of an input tag can only be passed to its own form. If you want to have a single input type file, you will have to use some JavaScript to handle your buttons, for example:

```js
getFormData = function() {
   const input = document.getElementById('file');
   const file = input.files[0];
   const formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("attachment", file);
   return formData;
}

submitFileToUrl1 = function() {
  const formData = getFormData();
  fetch('/url1', {method: "POST", body: formData});
}

submitFileToUrl2 = function() {
  const formData = getFormData();
  fetch('/url2', {method: "POST", body: formData});
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="file">
<button onclick="submitFileToUrl1()">First action</button>
<button onclick="submitFileToUrl2()">Second action</button>
```

Comment: cool... thanks will try this way. hope it works